# SED and Unicode Quotation Marks

Tags: sed, unicode

When testing against this string:

```
“… so that’s that… ”
```

The following should, but does not, match the opening quotation mark and following ellipsis and space:

```
sed "s/\([“‘\"']…\) /\1/g"
```

However, this correctly matches the second ellipsis and following space and closing quotation mark:

```
sed "s/… \([”’\"'.!?]\)/…\1/g"
```

If I split the first apart it works fine:

```
sed -e "s/\(“…\) /\1/g" \
-e "s/\(‘…\) /\1/g" \
-e "s/\(\"…\) /\1/g" \
-e "s/\('…\) /\1/g"
```

So why doesn't it work when it's grouped together? Especially when it works fine with the closing quotation marks.

Comment: I could be wrong about this, but in the second sed statement (sed "s/… \\([”’\"'.!?]\\)/…\1/g"), the 'dot' (in the square brackets; before the ! and ?) should match any character since it hasn't been escaped.  So you're looking for the ellipsis followed by a space, followed by any one character (or any of the other listed characters).

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case, as far as I can tell—the period does not seem to be acting as a wildcard when it's within the square brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of `sed` are you using? I believe that GNU sed should support Unicode characters, and your example works for me on Linux (Ubuntu, with UTF-8 environment).

If you are using a version of sed that is not Unicode-aware, your character group would break because it only matches one byte. If your command line is using a UTF-8 encoding, when you say `“` a non-Unicode-aware sed would actually see three bytes, `\xE2`, `\x80` and `\x9C`. This would cock up your character group which would only match one of those bytes at a time. Various other constructs would fail too, eg. `a”?` is the letter ‘a’ then two bytes followed by an optional third byte, so `a` on its own wouldn't match the expression though it looks like it should.

(You might want to consider also replacing the ellipsis character with three periods. Ellipsis is a compatibility character in Unicode; it's generally considered more modern to write out the periods and let the font take care of the typesetting.)

Comment: I'd been using whichever version of `sed` comes with OS X 10.6—wasn't able to determine what version that is—but I've just installed `gsed` and it works perfectly there. Thanks!

Regarding the ellipsis, this is for a personal project where I prefer the use of ellipsis characters over three periods, and if need be, it's easy enough to convert them later.

Comment: I think you've got that backwards: `...` is the compatibility version of a proper ellipsis `…`. It is not more modern to use `...` instead of `…`, and using the ellipsis glyph *is* letting the font do the correct thing—that's why the ellipsis glyph is there.